# How to pull records from DB in codeigniter into Datatable

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am new to codeigniter. I was given a project to work on. the person that did the application used Codeigniter. Datatable is used to display the rows from the DB. My task is to add another column (Image) to the table & display the image in the image column from the DB, but I couldn't figure out how I will add extra column from the DB to the view table. Code as below.

**View**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="big_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:1500px;">
<thead>
<tr style="font-size:14px;">
    <th style="width:120px"></th>
    <th>IP</th>
    <th style="width:200px;">Invoice</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Method</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Misc_Det</th>
    <th>NGN_Amount</th>
    <th style="width:170px;"></th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="font-size:14px;">


</tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
function tablesmanagertransactionadmin()
{

table = $('#big_table').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "dom": '<"pull-left"B><"pull-left bb"l><"bb pull-right"f>rt<"pull-left"i><"pull-right"<"#bb"p>>',

    "pageLength": 25,
    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [ ], //Initial no order.
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source

    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo base_url() ; ?>tablesmanagertransactionadmin",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [  ], //first column / numbering column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],
});

}
```

**Model**

```
function tablesmanagertransactionadmin()
   {

 $this->datatables->select('manual_payment_json,admin_transaction.id as idd,admin_transaction.ip as ipp,invoice_no as inv,invoice_no,admin_transaction.email as emx,login.verification_details as ver,sms_no,status,payment_method,date,login.frequent_payment_method as fre,r_details,o_details,vat,details,json_details,deposit_details',false)

  ->join('login', 'admin_transaction.email = login.email', 'left')
        ->from('transaction');

       $this->db->order_by('date','desc');

    $this->load->helper('My_helper');


        $this->datatables->edit_column('manual_payment_json','
        $3 $2 $1','formatorder(invoice_no,status,email),formattransdetails(details,json_details,deposit_details,manual_payment_json,invoice_no),formattranslink(invoice_no,details)');



          $this->datatables->edit_column('invoice_no',"
          $1",'formatinj(invoice_no,details)');

          $this->datatables->edit_column('details',"$1",'formatdeh(inv,status,email,sms_no)');


    return $this->datatables->generate();
  }
```

**Controller**

```
public function tablesmanagertransactionadmin()
    {
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()==TRUE && $this->session->userdata('admin_email')!="")
          {
    $data = $this->admin();

    $modules = $data['admin']->admin_module;
    $modules_arr = explode(",",$modules);

              if(!in_array("17",$modules_arr))
                    {
  echo "2";
  return;
                    }

  echo $this->adminmodel->tablesmanagertransactionadmin();
          }
    else
          {
   echo "2";
          }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: are you able to insert image into database??

Comment: yes. I am able to insert image into the database

Comment: the best way to see what you need to do, is to check with a `print_r($this->adminmodel->tablesmanagertransactionadmin())`and see how that image information looks like/does exist

Comment: then what is the problem in showing the image??

Comment: Thanks Kumar for your help, am grateful